# Ms Access query wih all tables MAX and COUNT the GUID field

Tags: ms-access, count, max

I need to make a form that will show me from all the tables in my database the MAX and the COUNT of the GUID (autonumber field). Is it possible to do it with one query?

Now I am do it with each table having a query. 
So if my database has 23tables, I have 23queries.

Thank you.

Comment: Would doing a UNION ALL of the 23 queries work?

Comment: Thanks... I test it by combining 3queries. My new problem is to make a field to show my the name of the table inside the query.

Comment: Just add a field to your select statement that contains the table name:  SELECT 'Table1' as Table, MaxValue, TableCount From Query1 UNION ALL SELECT 'Table2' as Table, MaxValue, TableCount From Query2...

Comment: Problem solved... So simple... Thank you... Kisses...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT 'Table1' as Table, MaxValue, TableCount From Query1 UNION ALL SELECT 'Table2' as Table, MaxValue, TableCount From Query2...
```